# Scan this from a text file into 2 arrays using C

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

Im having trouble parsing someething like this into an array.

So my text file test.txt has this line:
(1231212A, 1231212B)    (1231212C, 321128D)

im trying to scan this into an array but it needs to be divided up into parts

part1 of type int should be : 123

part2 : 12

part3 : 12

part4 (char): A

and I need to do this 4 times within the line

Here is the code i have but it is not working properly

```
{
int nums[1][12];
char chars[1][4];
FILE *file;

file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (file != NULL){

fscanf(file , "%*s%3d %2d %2d %s %*s %2d %2d %2d %s%*s        %*s%3d %2d %2d %s%*s %2d %2d %2d %s%*s" 
, &nums[0][0],&nums[0][1],&nums[0][2],&chars[0][0],&nums[0][3],&nums[0][4],&nums[0][5],&chars[0] 
[1],&nums[0][6],&nums[0][7],&nums[0][8],&chars[0][2],&nums[0][9],&chars[0][10],&nums[0][11],&chars[0] 
[3]);
}
```

when I print these arrays they do not print the right numbers and characters.
I need help with the fscanf part
Thank You

Comment: Why are you using `%*s` at the start of the format string? Just use a literal `(` to match an open parenth. Same for the commas and other parenths.

Comment: Also note that the `%s` directive reads characters until a whitespace is encountered, so this will read both the letter and the comma into the provided location.

Comment: Is there any reason for the 2D array of 1-row?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- I was assuming that OP plans on adding more lines of data.

Comment: Yes, that is what it looks like -- just somewhat odd.

Comment: Ahmad Malik, How should `321128D` get divided into 4 parts?

Answer (score 2):

After reading a *line* from the file with `fgets()`, parse the *string* with `sscanf()` including `"%n"` to detect how much was scanned.

Using *string literal* concatenation in the format helps too.

```
//                           v---not s
#define GROUP_FMT "%3d%2d%2d%c"

int n = 0;
sscanf(line, " (" GROUP_FMT " ," GROUP_FMT " ) (" GROUP_FMT " ," GROUP_FMT " ) %n",
  &nums[0][0], &nums[0][ 1], &nums[0][ 2], &chars[0][0], 
  &nums[0][3], &nums[0][ 4], &nums[0][ 5], &chars[0][1],
  &nums[0][6], &nums[0][ 7], &nums[0][ 8], &chars[0][2],
  &nums[0][9], &nums[0][10], &nums[0][11], &chars[0][3], &n);
// Did scanning reach the %n and was that the end of the string?
if (n && line[n] == '\0') Success();
else Fail();
```

Answer (score 2):

As @chux provided in his answer, the key is properly matching the format string with the data to be parsed, and then critically validating the return against the number of conversions anticipated. The primary errors in  your *format string* are your unnecessary inclusion of `%*s` (to try and skip `"("`) and `%s %*s` (to try and skip the comma) and `%s%*s %*s` (to try and skip `") "` in several locations which has the effect of reading the reading and discarding the entire first number, e.g. `"(1231212A,"` as a string, beginning the read of values in the second group of numbers and so on.

A closer match is as shown in @chux's answer or simply:

```
"(%3d%2d%2d%c, %3d%2d%2d%c) (%3d%2d%2d%c, %3d%2d%2d%c"
```

(that differs only in not providing for additional whitespace and doesn't read the number of characters consumed -- also note the closing `")"` isn't necessary in the format-string as your read of the final character, e.g. `'D'` ends the conversion)

While you are using a 2D array of 1-row, the following simplified example uses a 1D array for `chars` and `nums`, and could be written as follows to read with `fgets()` passing the buffer to `sscanf()` validating the return and either outputting the collected values or displaying an error if parsing fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC], chars[4];
    int nums[12];
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read line into buf with fgets() */
        /* parse with sscanf -- validate 16 conversions take place */
        if (sscanf (buf, "(%3d%2d%2d%c, %3d%2d%2d%c) (%3d%2d%2d%c, %3d%2d%2d%c",
            &nums[0], &nums[1], &nums[2], &chars[0],
            &nums[3], &nums[4], &nums[5], &chars[1],
            &nums[6], &nums[7], &nums[8], &chars[2],
            &nums[9], &nums[10], &nums[11], &chars[3]) == 16) {
            /* output result */
            printf ("%d %d %2d %c\n%d %d %2d %c\n%d %d %2d %c\n%d %d %2d %c\n",
                    nums[0], nums[1], nums[2], chars[0],
                    nums[3], nums[4], nums[5], chars[1],
                    nums[6], nums[7], nums[8], chars[2],
                    nums[9], nums[10], nums[11], chars[3]);
        }   /* or handle error */
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error parsing data from: %s\n", buf);
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/splitintoarr.txt
(1231212A, 1231212B) (1231212C, 321128D)
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitintoarr <dat/splitintoarr.txt
123 12 12 A
123 12 12 B
123 12 12 C
321 12  8 D
```

(the output of the final number has been output using the *field-width* modifier to ensure the columns remain aligned for your data)

Look things over in all answers and let us know if you have further questions.

Comment: Nice explanation.  Note that the final `")"` in the format serves no purpose nor does does scan used detect extra data in the line. But then, unfortunately, do many care about detecting ill form data.

Comment: I went for spaces in the format before the `"("`, ","`, "}"`, as a more lenient accepting of optional white-space there.  Perhaps better or not - depends on details of OP's unstated  goals.  IAC, another nice answer on your part.

Comment: Ooh, thank you. Yes, I noted the additional whitespace you provided for (nice touch), but when considering the answer, I decided to just go with the match of the input format (less flexible, but fewer rabbit-trails and caveats for the OP to take it). Fun, and good little question. Will certainly remove/explain the final `")"`.